# Windows "critical stop" sound when my project ends

Tags: c++, debugging, openal

I am creating a game engine (visual c++, opengl, ...) and it has come a long way. I have especially worked on memory safety and memory management.
Every part of the engine was created in separate projects so that they don't influence eachother until I am certain they are ok and then I integrate them in the engine.

Recently, I created a sound engine using OpenAL and if that project closes, I hear the windows sound that has been mapped to "critical stop". No error is popped up on screen and the program seems to exit normally.

Where/how should I start searching to find what's causing this? What can be causing this?

Edit: I just noticed that while debugging, I end up on "return 0" in _tWinMain, the debug log shows: "exited with code 3".

Comment: What does your windows application event log show?  Crashing applications are always shown in there.

Comment: Did you try running the program in a debugger? Every critical event should trigger the debugger to interrupt the program, giving you a backtrace and state snapshot of the process at the time the problem occured.

Comment: What *exactly* does "project closes" mean?  Do take a lead from the project goal, you'd expect an audio engine to make noises.  Surely the programmers that worked on it got a bit creative outside the box.

Comment: Windows application events shows nothing. Yes I run it in debugger all the time (Visual Studio 2008 pro). "Project closes" means, everything works fine, I push the X-button or press alt-f4, and everything stops fine, but a strange sound is there. Also, I just noticed that on my return 0 in _tWinMain, in the debuggers log "exited with code 3" shows... this must be the reason, but... why?

Comment: Code 3 is "The system cannot find the path specified.", i.e. failed tofind a folder. I suspect that you have some destructors/cleanup logic which is failing, so after you exit with `return 0` the cleanup logic runs. That fails, and exits with code 3.

Comment: That's very interesting! (where do I find a list of these codes?) I'll look into that!

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging powers (and a similar experience) tell me that you had an assertion failure (or other mechanism that tries to pop up a CRT debugging dialog box) during shutdown (e.g., in the destructor of a static object).  Shutdown has progressed far enough that the dialog could not be created.  The beep was to accompany the dialog, and the exit code 3 is one of the values that an assertion failure can return.

If you run in the debugger, I think you'll see the assertion failure that was intended for the dialog in the Output window.  If not, you might have to tweak the destination for CRT debug messages using [_CrtDebugReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hyw4sy7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).